# Receiving 401- Authorization required error while trying to access a public site with guest user in Salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites

We have provided all access on account object on the sites public access setting . 
The same is working on the dev sandbox but is not working in production. 
The field visibilty is also provided on account object

Comment: Is the relevant Visualforce page accessible to the Site Guest User profile?

Comment: Yes. Its accessible.